# Unity3d: keep working on the project in the editor while building for Android in command line

Tags: unity

Is it possible to keep working on the project in the editor while it's being built for Android in command line?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I thought about a few scenarios where it could possibly break and wanted to know for sure whether working on a project and building simultaneously  is a valid workflow.